# URL Redirection using IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I wish to redirect ALL pages from a specific folder and its subfolders to a page on root folder. I have written the following rule in IIS 7.5 but it is not working. Please advise.

```
<rule name="someName" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="/MoveFromThisFolder/.*" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/ToThisFile.html" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the rule as follows and it worked for me!

<rule name="SomeRule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^FromThisFolder/(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="ToThisFile.html" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

Answer (score -1):

Try getting rid of the leading "/"

```
<rule name="someName" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^MoveFromThisFolder/($|[\?/].*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="ToThisFile.html" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```